# operators overloading- multiply matrix with int in the left side

Tags: c++, class, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a matrix and scalar, lets call the matrix A. if I multiply the scalar to the matrix , when the scalar is on the right(2*A) it multiply all the indexes of the matrix by 2. BUT when I multiply the matrix with scalar on the left(A*2) it doesn't work!.(its should do as 2*A).
This is part of class(with members):

```
class Mat
{
private:
    int **matArray;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    bool validMat;
public:
 .../*functions*/
};
```

this is the function when of the right multiply:

```
Mat Mat::operator*(int scalarToMultiply){
    if(!validMat)
    {
        Mat resultOperator(0,0);
        return (resultOperator);
    }
    //Mat resultOperator(matToAdd.cols,matToAdd.rows);
    Mat resultOperator(cols,rows);
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            resultOperator.matArray[i][j]=matArray[i][j]*scalarToMultiply;
        }
    }
    return (resultOperator);
}
```

How do I do the other way?

Comment: Left-scalar multiplication (e.g. `2*A`) would require a free function `Mat operator*(int, Mat&)`, while right-scalar multiplication (e.g. `A*2`) could be either a member function like what you have above (`Mat Mat::operator*(int)`) or a free function `Mat operator*(Mat&, int)`. I think perhaps your characterizations in the question are backwards...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write the right-hand-side operator:

```
Mat operator*(int scalar, const Mat& rhs) {
    return rhs * scalar;
}
```

Comment: does this is function of the class Mat?

Comment: @hfghgjjhkhhfghgjjhkh Has to be a non-member function. Member operators take the class instance as the first arugment - so this one can't be a member.

Comment: so how do i get the Mat private members(like cols and rows) from the non-member function?

Comment: @hfghgjjhkhhfghgjjhkh make that public :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define `operator*` as a free function (after the class):

```
Mat operator*(int scalarToMultiply, const Mat& mat) { ... }
```

And if you need access to the private members, make it a `friend` of your class by adding

```
friend Mat operator*(int scalarToMultiply, const Mat& mat);
```

to your class.

If you plan to write `operator*`, you probably also want to support `operator*=`. To make your life easier, you can use libraries like [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/libs/utility/operators.htm) or [df.operators](https://github.com/d-frey/operators/). That way you only need to implement the basic operators and the libraries take care of generating the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have the `int` on the left hand side you need to have free function that has two parameters.  The you can call the `Mat` overloaded function inside free function.

```
Mat operator*(int lhs, Mat rhs)
{
    return rhs * lhs;
}
```